# Quay.io API image build

Tags: docker, coreos, mesosphere, quay.io

I am unable to build any image using quay REST API.
The only error I can see is:
Could not find or parse Dockerfile: First line in Dockerfile isn't FROM.

The dockerfile builds fine using other methods , the issue is only when using quay rest api.

This is the image build json:

```
{
  "docker_tags": [
    "v0.0.11"
  ],
  "archive_url": "http://host:port/app.zip"
}
```

The archive_url is accessible on local as well as on the network.
The build works if the url points to a Dockerfile, but fails if it points to a zip.
Are there any special requirements for this archive for quay server?

Comment: How are you building your image?

Comment: I'm using the quay rest api.